# gap between visits of more than 3 months- sql

Tags: sql

i am trying to identify the id's which are having gap between visits of more than 3 months

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    ID int,
    visit datetime);

INSERT INTO data (ID,visit)
VALUES
    (1,'1998-05-18 00:00:00.000'),
    (1,'1995-05-18 00:20:00.000'),
    (1,'1994-12-18 01:00:00.000'),
    (1,'1994-007-18 00:00:00.000'),
    (2,'2000-06-29 13:30:00.000'),
    (2,'2000-05-29 13:45:00.000'),
    (2,'2000-04-29 10:30:00.000'),
    (3,'2009-09-29 13:30:00.000'),
    (3,'2009-01-29 13:30:00.000'),
    (3,'2008-12-29 13:30:00.000');
```

Comment: Define "gap" here.  Does it mean that it has no nearest visit, either before or after, within 3 months?  Also, include the output and tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Also specify the expected result - as formatted text (no images.).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  `date`/`time` functions differ significantly among databases, but the idea is:

```
select distinct id
from (select d.*, lag(visit) over (partition by id order by visit) as prev_visit
      from data d
     ) d
where prev_visit < visit - interval '3 month';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82022c18fc606f0c55d15757a0e95ec0) is a db<>fiddle.  This uses SQL Server, so the `where` clause is:

```
where prev_visit < dateadd(month, -3, visit);
```

Comment: Thank you if in case I want to find out greater than 3 months or less than three months? I s there any way to do it @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @priya . . . You would adjust the date comparison logic in the `where`.

Comment: I tried to use where prev_visit < dateadd(month, ->3, visit);

Comment: tried where prev_visit < dateadd(month, ->3, visit); greater operator but troughed me error

Comment: I have tried  where prev_visit < dateadd(month, ->3, visit); greater operator but troughed me error - Gordon Linoff

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff  I have tried  where prev_visit < dateadd(month, ->3, visit); greater operator but troughed me error  Gordon Linoff